dunder name, main takes longer to execute than without?
Following a decorator tutorial then fiddled with the code halfway:
from time import perf_counter

def is_prime(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def count_prime_numbers(upper_bound):
    count = 0
    for num in range(upper_bound):
        if is_prime(num):
            count += 1
    print(f"Number of primes: {count}")
    return count

def benchmark(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Execution of {func.__name__} took {run_time:0.3f} seconds")
        return value

    return wrapper

def main():
    wrapper = benchmark(count_prime_numbers)
    value = wrapper(100000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This code has a run time of 0.132 seconds with the dunder name, main
But when I remove that, it only has a run time of 0.096 seconds.
Why does including dunder name, main cause a 38% increase to the run time?

Not my downvote, but this appears rather unclear. Do you mean you remove the if __name__ == '__main__': conditional and move the code out of main?

try running multiple times your code and you will notice a huge deviation of the times. You should average a lot of runs to get any meaningful results. Running a single time like you do will give you results that depend a lot on what your OS is doing at that particular moment.

If you remove the last two non-blank lines then nothing significant will happen when you run that file/code
